# How many viewport sizes is too many?

Tags: html, image, responsive-design, viewport, srcset

I figured out that using the *srcset* & *sizes* attributes are the best option for me. My question is how many viewports is the best to support? After writing this it seems like alot, but if the browser will pick the best one, and the others aren't loaded, why not just do a bunch so I can deliver the best experience for 1x and 2x users? Also should I consider 1.5x and 3x users? I only included the 1x sizes I would target. As you can imagine if I add 1.5x, 2x, and 3x sizes, this list will be insanely long. Here's the example:

```
<img src="image-320.jpg" sizes="100vw"
 srcset="image-320.jpg 320w, image-480.jpg 480w,
         image-768.jpg 768w, image-960.jpg 960w,
         image-1024.jpg 1024w, image-1280.jpg 1280w,
         image-1366.jpg 1366w, image-1680.jpg 1680w,
         image-1920.jpg 1920w, image-2048.jpg 2048w,
         image-2560.jpg 2560w, image-2880.jpg 2880w" alt="...">
```

Before I start this, I'm curious as to best practices and if I'm looking at this the right way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking around for the same answer and came across this article. The suggestions are based on empirical data and are skewed towards a full-width image, but it does provide a good starting point to working out which sizes we should be supporting.

https://medium.com/hceverything/applying-srcset-choosing-the-right-sizes-for-responsive-images-at-different-breakpoints-a0433450a4a3

The article suggests for `100vw` viewport the following sizes are recommended:

- 1920px (this covers FullHD screens and up)
- 1600px (this will cover 1600px desktops and several tablets in portrait mode, for example iPads at 768px width, which will request a 2x image of 1536px and above)
- 1366px (it is the most widespread desktop resolution)
- 1024px (1024x768 screens, excluding iPads which are hi-density anyway, are rarer, but I think you need some image size in between, not to leave too big a gap between pixel sizes, in case the market changes)
- 768px (useful for 2x 375px mobile screens, as well as any device that actually requests something close to 768px)
- 640px (for smartphones)

As an aside, I also found the following article very useful in understanding it all:

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/high-dpi/

I'm wondering whether you ever came across an answer to your query?